# Is there away to Use Label Text instead of popup confirmation Message?

Tags: user-behavior, copywriting, popup, confirmation, messages

On Mobile app, I am going to try to decrease and avoid user clicks. My idea is to display text (some words) on same page and use a `label` instead of using a `popup` confirmation message.

So, what is the best text (words) to display as `label` instead of Displaying "Are you sure you want to use credit" confirmation message?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're trying to avoid a click here. The confirmation messages you describe are designed to *add* a click in an effort to make sure the user has thought about what they are asking the system to do (make payments, use credits, delete files, etc.). Removing that click effectively removes 'sanity check'. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: actually i am trying to add a label on same page (like:if you select the credit you will use it on this order) ..that will help me to decrease number of user clicks..so i am trying to find a good words to use it instead of confirmation message ..

Comment: I'm still not sure *why* you want to remove clicks from the sanity check. The whole point of those confirmation messages is that the user *must* click to confirm that they understand. Without that click there is no sanity check.

Comment: actually i already have the "Next" button on credit page, so i already have button on this page,i am trying to avoid User Click Next then Click on Confirmation message ..,

Comment: What is with this weird idea that more clicks = more user frustration. The thing that **adds** user frustration is if the user is confused, doesn't find any reason as to why he is there, etc.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to avoid that click - that click ensures that the user understands that they are using credit. Without that click you reduce the message to background noise that the user will likely ignore: potentially a bad user experience.

Comment: let us say this is not important functionality, what is the good text to use as label instead of confirmation message

Comment: If it's not important functionality why do you need the text?

Comment: text will help user to take care about choosing one of credit or not

Comment: ...Which is why you need them to make an affirmative action with a click - it's like a safety catch on a gun: the gun doesn't just have "be careful" written on the side, the user has to make an affirmative action to release the catch to be able to shoot. The same is true of the click in a confirmation message. Removing that click effectively removes the point of the message.

Comment: thanks @AndrewMartin but on my case by default no credit is selected, that is why i need to display text instead of confirmation message .

Comment: Perhaps some mockups or screenshots might help better convey what you're trying to accomplish? I agree with all the comments here that extra clicks (especially in this situation) does not necessarily mean a worse user experience and removing the confirmation click step may be counterproductive to what you're trying to do.

Comment: that is what i am trying to do .. i am trying to avoid extra clicks

Comment: Less Clicks ≠ Good UX

Answer (score 1):

[image: Start Screen - Without label]

[image: End screen - With label]

I understand what you're talking about. We had a similar requirement in one of the apps we made for a client. The only way which this can make sense is if you have a little animation (in this case, the cards moving down and the lines on either side of the label being drawn outward). Still, this is a shaky UX area. And as to fixing the wording of the label, I suggest you try and use a exclamatory sentence. If the label needs a higher priority and attention, a contrasting color works well. I will try and make a small prototype for this once I get my mac from the repair store.

Cheers! Happy designing!